# python ubuntu and ImportError: libblpapi3_64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

How do I set a LD_LIBRARY_PATH in ubuntu 12.04?

in  .bashrc

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/blpapi_cpp/Linux
```

in /etc/environment

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/blpapi_cpp/Linux
```

The file exists

```
ls /home/ubuntu/blpapi_cpp/Linux/libblpapi3_64.so 
/home/ubuntu/blpapi_cpp/Linux/libblpapi3_64.so
```

sudo ldconfig

And yet I still get a importError: libblpapi3_64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/druidry-codebase/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import blpapi
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blpapi/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .internals import CorrelationId
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blpapi/internals.py", line 50, in <module>
    _internals = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blpapi/internals.py", line 46, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_internals', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libblpapi3_64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Could you try to run the command as this:
`sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ubuntu/blpapi_cpp/Linux ldconfig`

See if the problem persist or not.

Answer (score 1):

I added a line for LD_LIBRARY_PATH to my c++ SDK director in .profile and that fixed the issue.